# Libgdx play/pause music

Tags: java, android, libgdx, background-music

I'm new in LibGdx, actually I'm creating a simple Libgdx game for Android devices.

I'm facing to a problem with my play/pause music in LibGdx here is the simplified code.

```js
    //...
    
    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
      //...
      if(inputHelper.isTouched()){
            input.x = inputHelper.getScreenX();
            input.y = inputHelper.getScreenY();
            camera.unproject(input);
            
            if(soundRect.contains(input.x, input.y)){
                if(parent.getSound()) parent.pauseBackMusic();
                if(!parent.getSound()) parent.playBacMusic();
            }
        }
    }

  //...
  
  public void pauseBackMusic(){
  if(backMusic.isPlaying()){
   backMusic.pause();
   isSound = false;
  }
 }

 public void playBackMusic(){
  if(!backMusic.isPlaying()){
   backMusic.play();
   isSound = true;
  }
 }

 public Boolean getSound() {
  return isSound;
 }
```

As you can see in the code when I touch the **soundRect** it's looping between **pauseBackMusic() and playBackMusic()**.

Thank you.

Comment: Your naming doesn't make much sense. #getSound should be #isSound. Also, the Boolean should be replaced with the primitive equivalent. Your if statements can also be simplified with an else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Problem is that you use two if statements:

```
if(parent.getSound()) parent.pauseBackMusic();
if(!parent.getSound()) parent.playBacMusic();
```

So the first statement is true because `isSound = true`
Then you call method `pauseBackMusic()` in this method you set `isSound = false`

Then your next if statement tests: `!parent.getSound()` this is also true because: `isSound = false` and the method `playBacMusic()` set `isSound = true`

And it starts at the beginning by the next click.

Use else if statement instead:

```
if(parent.getSound()) parent.pauseBackMusic();
else if(!parent.getSound()) parent.playBacMusic();
```

So if `parent.getSound()` is true the else if statement will be skipped and `isSound` is still false. And by the next click only the else if statement will be true and the music will turn back on.

Or in this example you can simplify by only use else:

```
if(parent.getSound()) parent.pauseBackMusic();
else parent.playBacMusic();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [InputProcesser](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/InputProcessor.html) in order to listen to touch events. Using this, you can listen to a touch event that is only called once when a user presses your button unlike running in a constant loop like in your example.

You can do this by using the [touchDown](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/InputProcessor.html#touchDown-int-int-int-int-) Method